# Can Json.NET create readable json files?

Tags: c#, json, mono, json.net

I'm building an application in C# on Mono and am trying to use Json.NET to serialize objects to JSON. The problem I'm having is that the JSON being generated has no whitespace and isn't particularly readable.

```
[{"Title":"Third Post","Link":"http://example.com/third/link.html","Excerpt":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nibh velit, imperdiet id felis a, semper cursus tellus. Cras dapibus a libero at pharetra. Suspendisse nunc augue, elementum sit amet scelerisque vitae, luctus sed nulla.","Count":0},{"Title":"Second Post","Link":"http://example.com/second/link.html","Excerpt":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nibh velit, imperdiet id felis a, semper cursus tellus. Cras dapibus a libero at pharetra. Suspendisse nunc augue, elementum sit amet scelerisque vitae, luctus sed nulla.","Count":2},{"Title":"First Post","Link":"http://example.com/first/link.html","Excerpt":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nibh velit, imperdiet id felis a, semper cursus tellus. Cras dapibus a libero at pharetra. Suspendisse nunc augue, elementum sit amet scelerisque vitae, luctus sed nulla.","Count":6}]
```

I was hoping to generate something more like this:

```
[
    {
        "Title":"Third Post",
        "Link":"http://example.com/third/link.html",
        "Excerpt":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nibh velit, imperdiet id felis a, semper cursus tellus. Cras dapibus a libero at pharetra. Suspendisse nunc augue, elementum sit amet scelerisque vitae, luctus sed nulla.",
        "Count":0
    },
    {
        "Title":"Second Post",
        "Link":"http://example.com/second/link.html",
        "Excerpt":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nibh velit, imperdiet id felis a, semper cursus tellus. Cras dapibus a libero at pharetra. Suspendisse nunc augue, elementum sit amet scelerisque vitae, luctus sed nulla.",
        "Count":2
    },
    {
        "Title":"First Post",
        "Link":"http://example.com/first/link.html",
        "Excerpt":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nibh velit, imperdiet id felis a, semper cursus tellus. Cras dapibus a libero at pharetra. Suspendisse nunc augue, elementum sit amet scelerisque vitae, luctus sed nulla.",
        "Count":6
    }
]
```

Is there a way to get this kind of whitespace automatically added to the output?

Comment: (off-topic)A bit weird , cuz the whole point is to keep it as small as possible , and yo're trying to increase the file size....

Comment: In this case, the point isn't to keep the file as small as possible, it's to have manageable configuration files which can be edited on the fly by humans. Since the vast majority of the configuration is being done with key-value type information JSON is a natural fit, and requires far less ceremony than XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Formatting.Indented` value on the `Formatting` property of your `JsonWriter` like this:

```
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

If you just use the `JsonSerializer` then use the overloads of the `SerializeObject` method; some of them take a `Formatting` parameter which you can set to `Formatting.Indented`.

Comment: what chars does it use to break the lines ? is it platform independent ?

Comment: I believe it uses the `Environment.NewLine` property (which would be the most logical) but that has to be confirmed.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Confirmed (see `WriteIndent()` method of [`JsonTextWriter.cs`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextWriter.cs)). It uses `Environment.NewLine`, which according to the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx), equates to `\r\n` on non-Unix platforms and `\n` on Unix platforms.